# Como puedo agrupar por dia y trasponer salida de un query en postgresql

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Tengo un problema, he intentado crear una query que me sume el total de valores de un sensor agrupado por día. He intentado de mil manera y no lo consigo, alguien puede ayudarme?.

Un pequeño ejemplo de los datos que tengo:
Day                value    cod_sensor     hour
12/06/2016      85      SENSOR1      0:05:00
12/06/2016      10      SENSOR1      0:10:00
12/06/2016      25      SENSOR1      0:15:00
13/06/2016      26      SENSOR1      0:05:00
13/06/2016      87      SENSOR1      0:10:00
13/06/2016      42      SENSOR1      0:15:00
12/06/2016      44      SENSOR2      0:05:00
12/06/2016      53      SENSOR2      0:10:00
12/06/2016      12      SENSOR2      0:15:00
13/06/2016      29      SENSOR2      0:05:00
13/06/2016      95      SENSOR2      0:10:00
13/06/2016      38      SENSOR2      0:15:00
12/06/2016      61      SENSOR3      0:05:00
12/06/2016      50      SENSOR3      0:10:00
12/06/2016      15      SENSOR3      0:15:00
13/06/2016      18      SENSOR3      0:05:00
13/06/2016      33      SENSOR3      0:10:00
13/06/2016      72      SENSOR3      0:15:00

Y necesito una consulta que me de una salida con la suma de los sensores por dia, algo así:

Day                  SENSOR1         SENSOR2         SENSOR3
12/06/2016      120                 109                 116
13/06/2016      155                 162                 123

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir la query que has intentado y no funciona? Podría ser un buen punto de partida para otros usuarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Extension Tablefunc

Puedes usar la extension [*tablefunc*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) que viene en el modulo contrib.
Esta extensión posee una función llamada `crosstab` que pivota las tablas. Es decir convierte filas del tipo EAV en columnas.

Tienes que crear la extension primero. Este ejemplo lo crea en el esquema *public*

```
midb=# CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc WITH SCHEMA public;
```

**Tabla pivotada**

Este query debería realizar lo que necesitas. Acuerdate de ajustar los nombres de las tablas, campos y tipos de datos a tu caso en particular.

```
select * from public.crosstab (
'SELECT fecha, cod_sensor, sum(valor)
 FROM public.sensor_data
 GROUP BY fecha, cod_sensor ORDER BY fecha, cod_sensor'
) as ct(fecha date, "SENSOR1" numeric, "SENSOR2" numeric, "SENSOR3" numeric)
```

## Agrupamiento

Puedes hacerlo tambien sin instalar nada. Directamente con las funciones de agrupamiento disponibles por defecto.

El query sería:

```
select fecha, 
  max (case when cod_sensor = 'SENSOR1' then valor end) as "SENSOR1",
  max (case when cod_sensor = 'SENSOR2' then valor end) as "SENSOR2",
  max (case when cod_sensor = 'SENSOR3' then valor end) as "SENSOR3"
from 
(
  SELECT fecha, cod_sensor, sum(valor) valor
  FROM public.sensor_data 
  GROUP BY fecha, cod_sensor ORDER BY fecha, cod_sensor
) a
group by fecha
```

Comment: Perfecto!!! Gracias. a todos por compartir su conocimiento.

Comment: Podes aceptar mi respuesta como buena entonces :)

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando `group by` y agregaciones `sum` debería de ser fácil:

```
select [day], SUM(value) as Total, cod_sensor
from tableName
group by [day], cod_sensor
```

Esto lo que haría sería darte un resultado así:

**day**                         **Total**                             **cod_sensor**

12/06/2016       120                                 SENSOR1

12/06/2016       109                                 SENSOR2

12/06/2016       123                                 SENSOR3

13/06/2016       155                                 SENSOR1

13/06/2016       162                                 SENSOR2

13/06/2016       123                                 SENSOR3

Cómo lo que quieres es en una única línea tener todos los sensores sería necesario hacer otras operaciones. Confírmame si el resultado actual es suficiente; en caso contrario investigo más.

Comment: Esto debería ser un comentario ya que, como respuesta, no resuelve el OP.

Comment: No puedo añadir un comentario con este código que se entienda.. Por eso hago respuesta y pregunto si es suficiente (estoy investigando de mientras)

Comment: Gracias miguel, no me da

Comment: Sólo tienes 3 sensores o puede haber N cod_sensor?

Comment: Si miguel, pueden ser N sensores!

Answer (score 0):

Pues bien, yo creo que hay varias formas de solucionar este query, yo te voy a mostrar uno de ellos:

**SQL**

```
    SELECT tbl.`day`,
    (SELECT SUM(tbls1.`value`) FROM `tu_tabla` AS tbls1 WHERE tbls1.`cod_sensor` = 'SENSOR1' AND tbls1.`day` = tbl.`day`) AS SENSOR1, 
    (SELECT SUM(tbls1.`value`) FROM `tu_tabla` AS tbls2 WHERE tbls2.`cod_sensor` = 'SENSOR2' AND tbls2.`day` = tbl.`day`) AS SENSOR2,
    (SELECT SUM(tbls1.`value`) FROM `tu_tabla` AS tbls3 WHERE tbls3.`cod_sensor` = 'SENSOR3' AND tbls3.`day` = tbl.`day`) AS SENSOR3,
    FROM `tu_tabla` AS tbl 
    GROUP BY tbl.day
```

Te explíco:

Básicamente solo se crean 3 subconsultas de la misma tabla *"tu_tabla"* donde condicionamos el cod_sensor y Sumamos el total del value.

Espero te sirva para dar claridad al problema.